# Swift / Spring: SoundPlayer.play("string.wav") not working

Tags: spring, swift

I try to use the Spring Framework to play a sound when a button is touched.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//TODO: max, mia, beide arrays und zufallsgenerator und happy day unten mit klick gleich wave



@IBAction func soundButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mySound : String! = "refresh.wav"

    SoundPlayer.play(mySound)

    }


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: SpringImageView!

@IBAction func beideButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "b1")
    imageView.animation = "zoomIn"
    imageView.animate()


}

@IBAction func maxButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "max1")
    imageView.animation = "slideLeft"
    imageView.animate()

}

@IBAction func miaButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "mia1")
    imageView.animation = "slideRight"
    imageView.animate()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I get the following error: **Cannot invoke 'play' with an argument list of type ('String')**

I tried view things like as!, as String, as String!, as? String to unwrap or so but can not figure it out...

Here is the SoundPlayer class (Copyright (c) 2015 James Tang (j@jamztang.com):

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

public class SoundPlayer: NSObject {

@IBInspectable var filename : String?
@IBInspectable var enabled : Bool = true

private struct Internal {
    static var cache = [NSURL:SystemSoundID]()
}

public func playSound(soundFile:String) {

    if !enabled {
        return
    }

    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundFile, withExtension: nil) {

        var soundID : SystemSoundID = Internal.cache[url] ?? 0

        if soundID == 0 {
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &soundID)
            Internal.cache[url] = soundID
        }

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)

    } else {
        println("Could not find sound file name `\(soundFile)`")
    }
}

@IBAction public func play(sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let filename = filename {
        self.playSound(filename)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the code alone (I'm not familiar with Spring), what you need to do is create a `SoundPlayer` instance and call `playSound` on it (not `play`, which uses an internal `filename` for the sound to play instead of its argument), like this:

```
@IBAction func soundButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mySound : String! = "refresh.wav"

    let soundPlayer = SoundPlayer()
    soundPlayer.playSound(mySound)

    }
```